# Youtube Subscription not working Properly

Tags: php, html, youtube, youtube-api

I have used following code to create youtube subscribe button on my website

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>
```

Its working fine when the user already logged into their google account.

If user not logged in it will open google login window, after login login window closed automatically but subscription not work. Showing below error in my console

[image]

If I reload the same page it will work fine. Which means the user already logged in with google account.

I have tried with oauth. But I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of open issues on Google's issues tracker regarding this problem. It seems that this has been going on for a long time now and that Google Developers doesn't seem to put much attention to this issue.

Check out some of the issues posted [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7740&can=1&q=subscription%20button&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)
and [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7740&can=1&q=subscription%20button&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary).

Trying to handle it using callbacks instead to implement your code seems to have the same problem too. Check that one out [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5707&can=1&q=subscription%20button&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary).